# Postgres max_wal_size and wal_keep_size parameter

Tags: postgresql, transaction-log, master-slave-replication

I am setting up Postgres v14 database. I have a question related to the `max_wal_size` and `wal_keep_size` parameters.

According to the documentation:

`max_wal_size` ⇒ Maximum size to let the WAL grow during automatic checkpoints. This is a soft limit; WAL size can exceed `max_wal_size` under special circumstances, such as heavy load, a failing `archive_command`, or a high `wal_keep_size` setting.

`wal_keep_size` ⇒ Specifies the minimum size of past log file segments kept in the `pg_wal` directory, in case a standby server needs to fetch them for streaming replication.

What will happen if the value of `wal_keep_size` is greater than the value of `max_wal_size`, and the standby server is slow and lagging in replication by more than `wal_keep_size`?
`wal_keep_size` worth of data will be retained in the WAL directory on the primary. But since the WAL files size exceeded `max_wal_size`, will the checkpoint keep running until the size comes down below `max_wal_size`?

Answer (score 4):

The behavior or lag on the standby side does not influence the behavior of the primary server, as far as these parameters are concerned. If the standby falls behind by more than `wal_keep_size`, it is dead, but the primary doesn't care.

Also, the duration of a checkpoint doesn't influence how many WAL segments are deleted. A checkpoint flushes all data modifications prior to a certain log sequence number (LSN) to disk. The checkpoint can be triggered by `max_wal_size`, but its duration is not directly dependent on how much WAL there is.

There *is* a connection between checkpoints and WAL size, but that only comes into play when the checkpoint is done. At that point, PostgreSQL deletes or recycles WAL segments that are no longer needed. The number of WAL segments recycled depends on a heuristic that takes the amount of recently written WAL into account, and the only important concern is that there have to be at least `min_wal_size` worth of WAL segments for future use. `max_wal_size` does not come into play here at all.

`max_wal_size` is one of the most misunderstood PostgreSQL parameters. For obvious reasons, people think that it is a kind of size limit for WAL. In reality, it only governs when checkpoints are started. Sure, WAL is deleted at the end of a checkpoint, so there is a connection to WAL size, but that is somewhat coincidental.

`wal_keep_size` does not enter into this at all. Checkpoints are not triggered by the size of `pg_wal`, but by the amount of WAL written *since the last checkpoint*.

Comment: My question is about checkpoint being triggered when wal size become greater than max_wal_size. supppose
wal_keep_size = 2GB
max_wal_size = 1GB
and standby fail. wal will keep accumulating upto 2GB making it greater than 1GB(max_wal_size).
then checkpoint will keep getting triggered irrespective of checkpoint interval specified by checkpoint_timeout.  No ?

max_wal_size is most misunderstood because the name is not very intuitive.

Comment: I added a sentence that should explain that.

Comment: Should not the second sentence be *"If the standby falls behind by more than* **wal_keep_size** *, it is dead..."* ? And the last sentence should be *"...* **not** *by the size of pg_wal, but by the amount of WAL..."*

Comment: @Edheldil Right on both accounts. I have fixed the answer; thanks.

Comment: I would add perhaps that the relationship that exists between the 2 is that the max wal data size is what is gathered between checkpoints and therefore can trigger a checkpoint (size or time) and after those checkpoints it can choose to recycle wal files. The wal_keep_size is used for the buffer of data needed to catch up a standby if it falls behind its pg wal writes so that it doesn't have to do a full resync. You would probably want a 50% - 75% less keep size than your max wal size because of the checkpoint charectaristic and recovery relationship.

Comment: @ChristianMatthew If you use `wal_keep_size` to allow your standby to keep up, you will typically have to set it to quite high values.

Comment: hi @LaurenzAlbe can you explain that. how should I think about the values I set? I have no clue how to approach this other than observing it in actual usage so I can glean how much it is using. What do you recommend to start with?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Exactly: you measure how much WAL is written per hour, and if you want the standby to survive three hours of downtime, set `wal_keep_size` thrice as high.

Comment: Thank you. And do you agree with the +50-75% for max wal size?

Comment: @ChristianMatthew No, that is completely bogus. How much WAL you need to retain for the standby to be able to catch up is totally unrelated to `max_wal_size`, which governs checkpoints (and not the size of `pg_wal`). Just try to understand the mechanics rather than clinging to cookbook recipes.